# Xastir interface text not appearing

Tags: gui

I've just installed Xastir on an Ubuntu Groovy box. When trying to use it, important parts of the interface text don't appear (per screenshot)

[image: Invisible text in Xastir on Ubuntu]

(Entries are definitely present, I can select different "Interface Types" per the visible selector, I just can't see what they are!)

I *suspect* (based on button text) that it's rendering white text on a white background.

This is a clean install of Ubuntu-packaged Xastir on a relatively vanilla Ubuntu Groovy box (recently upgraded from Focal where the same issue occurred).

I've wiped `~/.xastir`, this hasn't helped. I've looked in `~/.xastir/config/xastir.cnf` and tried poking assorted `*_FONT` config values, which hasn't helped.

My suspicion is that this is some kind of system / X-based config issue, but I'm not familiar enough with the tooling to really debug it. I can't reproduce it in another application but I've not found anything that uses similar window rendering. It *could* be a Xastir issue, but it doesn't feel like it.

How could I debug this further please?

Comment: Seems to be theming issue. Shows normally on MATE.